# Laravel 5.6 Model HasManyThrough Relationships of 3 Tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to make a relationship between 3 tables of Laravel

```
+---------------+  +---------------+  +-------------------+
|  venue_images |  |  transactions |  | image_transaction |
+---------------+  +---------------+  +-------------------+
|   id          |  |   id          |  |  venue_image_id   |
|   user_id     |  |   user_id     |  |  transaction_id   |
+---------------+  +---------------+  +-------------------+
```

Here's my code but it's not working.

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ImageTransaction::class ,VenueImage::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I want to join the three tables using transaction id and venue image id

on my controller

```
 $transactions = transaction::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('images')->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood your question you have a `pivot` table `image_transaction` which is [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. Eloquent automatically arrange pivot table's name alphabetically like `transactions_venue_image` so you need to pass your custom name `image_transaction` in the parameter. [[docs]](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

In your **VenueImage** Model

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Transaction','image_transaction');
}
```

In your **Transaction** Model

```
public function venue_images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\VenueImage','image_transaction');
}
```

There are also 3rd and 4th parameters which are foreign keys of the related model which are explained better in the docs.

In your **Controller**

```
$transactions = transaction::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('venue_images')->get();
```

Comment: @Namoshek is this more appropriate than using the hasManyThrough relationship? because the answer below from Adrian Hernandez-Lopez also worked for me. But what should be the best answer for this?

Comment: @Vincent HasManyThrough is meant for a relation between A and C in a situation where A hasMany B and B hasMany C. In other words, A hasMany C through B.

Comment: Sorry, forgot something. The important point is that A, B and C are entities (models) and not tables. A pivot table is just a technical thing that allows us to have a manyToMany relation. It is not an entity.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the parameters to the hasManyThrough function looks wrong. According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

> The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the name of the intermediate model.

So in your case it should be like this (without defining the foreign keys)

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function images() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(VenueImage::class, ImageTransaction::class);
    }
}
```

If this does not work try to include the keys as described in the documentation:

> Typical Eloquent foreign key conventions will be used when performing the relationship's queries. If you would like to customize the keys of the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments to the hasManyThrough method. The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model. The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model. The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument is the local key of the intermediate model.

Comment: @Vincent I have tested this code and it works in a similar case Users like a project so in order to get the projects a user likes I can do it as follows `public function likedProjects(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Project::class, Like::class, 'user_id', 'id', 'id', 'project_id');
    }`. In your case `function images(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(VenueImage::class, ImageTransaction::class, 'transaction_id', 'id', 'id', 'venue_image_id');
    }` should wok.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
class Transaction extends Model
    {
        public function images(){
            return $this->belongsToMany(ImageTransaction::class ,VenueImage::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
        }
    }
```